# Powershell script error processing CSV data

Tags: powershell, csv, gethostbyname

I'm writing a script to load computer names from a CSV file, then look up their IP addresses.

The script creates an error when using the name from the CSV.

If I run the script in ISE, the error shows up, but the result still comes though.  If I run the script from powershell, it errors and the result is null.

If I substitute the `$PCname = $_.System` for `$PCname = "Computer01"` everything works fine.

If I write-host `$_.System` it displays `"Computer01"`. How can I get this to work in powershell?

```
$file = "\\server.contoso.net\private$\Systems.csv";
$CSV = Import-CSV $file;

$CSV | %{
    if ($_.Skip -eq 0)
    {
        $PCname = $_.System
       # $PCname = "Computer01"
        write-host $PCname
        try
        { 
            $ipaddress = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName($PCname).AddressList[0].IpAddressToString
        }
        Catch [system.exception]
        { 
            if(1)
            { $error[0].tostring() }
        }
    }
}
```

Error displayed is:

> Exception calling "GetHostByName" with "1" argument(s): "The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found"

Comment: Is anything [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/373890/ec2-hosted-asp-net-not-stable) helpful?

Comment: What is the error that you're getting?

Comment: Nothing there seemed helpful. I've rebooted and reset the tcp/ip stack, issues persists.

Comment: @KevinD the error is at the bottom of the post.

Comment: What do you see if you add `Write-Host "'$PCName'"` as your log string

Comment: log string? If I place `Write-Host "'$PCName'"` in the `Catch` clause, it comes back: `'Computer01    '`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the values in the CSV at some point had whitespace added after them, which caused a name look up error.  I'm not sure why ISE would still be able to look up the host, but removing the whitespace fixed the issue.

Thanks to sha, his recommendation helped me see the whitespace.